# Understanding Time Complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

Can some one help me to understand the time complexity for the below code. The program is for shifting all the zeros to the right of an array.

```
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String []s = br.readLine().split(" ");

        int a[] = new int[s.length];

        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
            a[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);


        int j= a.length-1;
        int i=0;

        while(j>=0 && i<a.length-1 && j-i>0){
                if(a[i]==0){
                    while(a[j]==0)
                    j--;
                    int temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
                i++;
        }

        for(int k:a)
            System.out.print(k+" ");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating time complexity will be difficult if we try to include the  `a[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);`since in `Integer class` , `parseInt()`method runs inside a `while loop`, and depending on the length of the passing String, it will gives different time complexity, but if we assume that it will take O(F(q)), the time complexity of your code will be `O(s.length^2)+O((s.length)*O(F(q))`